# What is soy chicken and how is it prepared?

Tags: chicken, soy

In many places in the US, I have eaten something called Soy Chicken varieties. I would like to know how this is prepared. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I edited this question because I think there were two distinguishable questions. If OP wants the other question answered too, feel free to ask it again as a new question, but I don't think that would work here.

Comment: Is this really about chicken or a product made to have a similar texture as chicken, but is actually made of soy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soy chicken is usually available at Asian grocery stores that cater to an East Asian demographic. It is normally sold as "soy ham" or "veggie ham", with "chicken" as one of the varieties available. It's usually in a sort of log shape and you just cut it to whatever size you need.  It is technically already cooked, but many recipes will call for it to be coated and baked, etc.

Comment: That sounds just awful. :)

Comment: @Jolenealaska If you get over the whole "imitation meat" thing, and especially if you find one that doesn't have weird artificial meat flavor, it's actually not bad at all. It has an substantial texture, isn't prone to overcooking like meat is, and works well in dishes with other flavors. And chicken doesn't have that much flavor to begin with, so you're really not losing much.

Comment: "Soy chicken is usually available at Asian grocery". - I could not find it in any Indian supermarket or grocery store, despite being Asian grocery stores.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I made it more specific.